# Treeview cannot be null

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, treeview

I am getting an error that makes no sense when saving a table created within VS2012, SQL Express 2008 R2.

```
Item in the Virtualizing TreeView cannot be null
```

This is a table save not a rebuild, unless that happens anyway. But I do not get this error at any other time, even after creating  new web page, or saving changes to an existing page.

Really not sure where to look for the cause. I have not changed any of the pages that use the treeview in over 3 years. They are in a totally different part of the web site.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Same damn thing here. Using System.Data.SQLite's provider if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem some time ago and landed here to see not much solution has been provided.

What I found is that, if that instance of VS is closed and a new instance is reopened then that error is getting resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can go to server explorer in VS and right click on your connection. It will ask you for Database Diagramming select yes for it. Now you will not get this error.